# Is it possible to do a command line project upgrade and compile from Visual C# 2005 to Visual C# 2008 Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-express

Using the full version of Visual C# 2008 Express, it looks like you could use

```
devenv SolutionFile | ProjectFile /upgrade
```

But is there a similar way using Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the project files are the same.

The solution file has 2 differences in the versions at the top. Just increment each one.

So write a simple commandline app to do that conversion for you, and then proceed as normal with 2008.